# Capacitor Sqlite gives 'Error CapacitorSQLitePlugin :null" only in production not all devices

Tags: android, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

My Capacitorjs app uses the capacitorcommunity SQLite plugin.

It used to run fine in Production.

After various modifications and plugin updates, which tested fine in development/debug mode.  I deployed it to android play-store for testing.

It runs fine in debug mode on a Samsung A53 5G (Android 13) the deployed version on the same device gives error: CapacitorSQLitePlugin :null when calling createConnection.

Install from Playstore to an older device with Android 9 runs fine.

Versions:

- capacitor/sqlite plugin 5.4.2-2
- capacitor 5.5.1
- android 5.5.1

my attempts to resolve:

- roll back recent updates
- clean project,
- clear cache,
- reinstalled SQLite including some previous versions

All without resolve

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Best regards.

I was just having that same error and after researching in several places, issues; then a solution that worked very well for me and I want to share it. The solution is to add **android:allowBackup="false"** in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file; which is located in the path **android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml**. Then everything is uninstalled and reinstalled.

Thank you for your attention and I hope I could help you.

Reference link:
[Plugin failed to register in Android 11 physical device](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/issues/196#issuecomment-1033881434)
[Ionic Capacitor SQLite won’t initialize in Android ONLY through the Play Store](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-capacitor-sqlite-wont-initialize-in-android-only-through-the-play-store/229223/2)